# JQuery issue - .dialog is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I know this has been posted before but I'm looking for some explanation as well as a fix.

Working on a pretty simple grid/details view page in MVC using JQuery datatables as well as the JQueryUI dialog function.

I'm loading the following files:

```
   <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-datatables/datatables.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-datatables/datatables.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/json2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now if I remove the function that opens the dialog, it works fine, otherwise the datatables call doesn't get loaded and I get the ".dialog is not a function error".

Now I get that there's conflicting JQuery files here but I don't really understand how to sort that out.  Do the JQuery UI and datatables need to have the exact same JQuery file?

EDIT

Okay, moved the files to show as such:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-datatables/datatables.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-datatables/datatables.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

same error

and the function that's  blowing up is

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
    $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 950,
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        title: $(this).attr("RequestDetalis"),
        show: "fade",
        hide: "fade",
        closeOnEscape: true,
    });

    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is the jQuery library being imported after jQuery datatables?

Comment: No real reason, was just moving stuff around.  Moved the jQuery links above it, same error.

Comment: You need it above all jquery dependant scripts. Have you made sure your custom code is imported beneath jquery also? Can you put your custom code in the question?

Comment: This custom code, is this being imported after the jquery library or before?

Comment: After, it's at the bottom of the page

Comment: Can you edit [this fiddle](https://jsbin.com/kayekepoja/edit?html,css,js,console,output) to help me understand the problem better?

Comment: Can you view this:
https://jsbin.com/fenihi/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126128/discussion-between-evolutionxbox-and-trevorgoodchild).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the problem was that there was a newer version of JQuery included in the datatables.js file.  I downloaded the files individually, works fine now.